# ROR:How can I get the params from controller without reloading the browser?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with some gmaps API now and I pass lat and log through the gem "gon". Since I want the markers to be the latest, I'll need latest lat and log. How can I pass the params from controller to view.html without reloading the whole page?

**controller.rb**

```
@targetrecords.each do |targetrecords|

  pnts[i][0]=targetrecords.latitude
  pnts[i][1]=targetrecords.longitude
  pnts[i][2]=targetrecords.address
  pnts[i][3]=targetrecords.created_at

end

gon.pnts=pnts
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var centlat = (gon.pnts[0][0]+gon.pnts[1][0]+gon.pnts[2]  
               [0]+gon.pnts[3][0])/4;
var centlng = (gon.pnts[0][1]+gon.pnts[1][1]+gon.pnts[2]   
               [1]+gon.pnts[3][1])/4

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 14,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(centlat,centlng),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

</script>
```

there are more in the view, but just something like that which I want it up to date with a click or something.

Comment: Are you interested in a pure Javascript solution, or is a jQuery solution acceptable to you?

Comment: If it can be applied to ROR, I'm ok with everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the gem gon, if you followed the setup correctly, you can do this in your controller:

```
def your_action
  gon.your_variable = your_ruby_variable
end
```

And now you can access it in your javascript. To try it, you could do:

```
console.log(gon.your_variable)
```

and your should be able to see it in your browser's console.

You can also use an ajax request, but since you asked about gon, this should work.

EDIT: to get updates after the first page load, you can use gon watch
https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-gon-watch

Comment: thanks!But I can access the param in my Js. My problem is that after first load A=1 and the param A from the database has already changed to 2 maybe a minute later. But I want the latest value without reloading the whole page.Can I do that with gon?

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It seem really really helpful. I'll try it!!

Comment: @林易瑩 glad to help ! Please accept my answer if you consider the question answered.